# Appcmd Syntax for Arrays in Powershell

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to run the following to set the handler mappings for each of our websites using appcmd in powershell:

```
$websites = Get-ChildItem IIS:\Sites
foreach ($Site in $WebSites) {
C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config "$site" /section:handlers -accessPolicy:"Read,Script,Execute"}
```

However I'm getting this error message for each site as it iterates through them:

```
ERROR ( message:Cannot find SITE object with identifier "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement". )
```

What am I doing wrong?  I tried using a property of the $sites variable:

```
$site.name
```

but even that doesn't work.  I'm at a loss.  Thanks!

Comment: Try `appcmd set config "$($site.Name)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've encountered, `"$site"` doesn't expand to the name of the website, but to the ***type*** of object that `$site` refers to. `"$site.name"` is not way off, but in fact:

```
"$site"      -eq "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement"
"$site.name" -eq "Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElement.name"
```

The PowerShell parser stops recognizing the variable name at `.`, and treats the rest (`".name"`) as a string.

You can use the `$()` sub-expression operator to escape an entire statement:

```
"Name: $($site.name)"
```

---

You can do anything you like inside `$()` and nest them all you like:

```
"Random Site Name: $("$(Get-Random -Maximum ([int32]::MaxValue)){0}" -f $site.name)"
```